# How to compile golang source code in windows

Tags: compiler-construction, go

I want to compile the source code of golang (http://golang.org/dl/go1.3.src.tar.gz). Because I want to leran the technologies of compilation, even I will modify the sources codes of go compiler. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Attention, I just want to compile it in windows, not in linux. Thanks!

Comment: Compiling Go on Windows in much more difficult than compiling it on Linux, you know?

Comment: @FUZxxl: It's not that difficult.

Comment: @peterSO Typing ./all.bash into a terminal is simpler than having to install a toolchain manually as Windows does not provide one by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit more complicated on windows than on Linux

1. You have to install the [MinGW GCC](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite) tool chain and make sure you put it in your path.

   - Not going into details because the official HOWTO on that link is very detailed.
2. Download Go's source, unpack it, open a terminal and `cd path-to-go/src`.
3. run `all.bat`, if all goes well you should get `ALL TESTS PASSED` printed out after a while.

Comment: I was literally doing this today and honestly - the instructions here are a perfect subset of the ones in the documentation. It literally isn't any harder than this. +1 to undo the stupid downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me. I can get both 32 bit and 64 bit go working on windows 7 and 8.1 using this method:

[Go WindowsBuild](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsBuild)

You might like to also give this a go.

[Go MinGW](https://code.google.com/p/gomingw/)